# How to create a action button which changes its color whenever underlying View has changed until ApplicationUser visits this View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In my application used only by `ApplicationUser`, there are no `[AllowAnonymous]` actions besides login.

I would like achieve behaviour known from forums but because there is going to by only one View for which I need this behaviour probably there are several solutions.

There is a view `Index.cshtml`  for `Index()` action of `AnnouncmentController`

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Announcment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

RENDERING ANNOUNCEMENTS
```

In `_Layout.cshtml` I would like to add:

`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Announcments", "Announcment")</li>`

which will change color to RED after user logs in and there is any new announcment.

Is there any quick way to do this? There will be no more buttons like this in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to use child actions. First, you add a new action to your controller:

**AnnouncementController**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult AnnouncementsLink()
{
    bool hasNewAnnouncments = false;

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        hasNewAnnouncements = // check for new announcements for user
    }

    return PartialView("_AnnouncmentsLink", hasNewAnnouncements);
}
```

*Note: `[AllowAnonymous]` is necessary for this child action because it's going to be used in the layout and at the very least, on the sign in page, the user will be anonymous. If you don't allow anonymous, the user will be redirected to the sign in page in order to render the child action, which would then require the user to sign in before viewing, so they would be redirected again, etc. Essentially, you end up with a nasty endless redirect that will eventually result in a 500 error.*

**Views\Announcement\_AnnouncementLink.cshtml**

```
@model bool

@if (Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Announcements", "Announcement", new { @class = "highlight" })
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Announcements", "Announcement")
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<li>@Html.Action("AnnouncementsLink", "Announcement")</li>
```

Then, of course, you'd want to add a style declaration for `.highlight`:

```
#nav .highlight {
    color: red;
}
```